# HTTP Error 414. The request URL is too long using ActionLink

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my page I am creating ActionLinks based on my client's first name, last name, history etc. 
When the client history is too long, I am getting a 414 error.

```
public class SearchViewModel
{
    public char[] Alphabet => "ΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΟΠΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩ".ToCharArray();

    public char ClientSearchString { get; set; }
    public List<ClientViewModel> ClientsList { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Dob { get; set; }
    public bool Edit { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Job { get; set; }
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public string LastVisit { get; set; }
    public string Record { get; set; }
    public string Pit { get; set; }
    public string Er { get; set; }
    public string Ter { get; set; }
    public string History { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool OldRecord { get; set; }
}

@foreach (var client in clientList)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(client.LastName))
    {
       <tbody id="rounded-corner">
        <tr id="rounded-corner">
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink(client.LastName, "DisplayClientDo", "DisplayClient", client, null)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => client.FirstName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => client.Dob)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => client.Address)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => client.Telephone)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(x => client.LastVisit)
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody> 
}


public ActionResult DisplayClientDo(ClientViewModel model)
{
    return View("DisplayClient", model);
}
```

The page fails in the browser I think. The URL is about 18000 characters long (due to history)

And [this](https://pastebin.com/Se1KRGWi) is the url resulting from the ActionLink

Any clues how to fix this?

Comment: Is the last name 18 000 characters long?

Comment: No, the client's history is

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. URLs should not be so long. Why are you generating such URLs?

Comment: Because I am posting all this info from the ActionLink to another view that renders each element to a textbox for editing

Comment: I noticed your pastebin now. You are serializing the entire client object into the request. Why? The standard way would be to just reference the client by a clientID or similar.

Comment: You should either be passing an ID (the most common) or POSTing the data, not passing it through an URL.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. That comes from an old database without IDs unfortunately.

Comment: How can I change this to POST the data instead and still create ActionLinks based on my search results?

Comment: How do you plan to handle the update? How do you identify a specific post in the database?

Comment: My bad, it does have IDs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the pastebin url it looks like your route is taking one of the fields from the client object as the ID (the 894 value). The normal advice would be to ONLY send that ID to the next page, and to reload the history from the database. That way you dont have to pass around lots of data which could go stale / be sensitive etc.

I would try and identify the field which is the key for the record and just pass that. If the field was called ID it would be something like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink(client.LastName, "DisplayClientDo", "DisplayClient", new { client.ID }, null)
```

Comment: This works somewhat, it goes to the next page, many thanks! Now at the next page all my textboxes are empty though. They are in the form of :
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveEditsAndReturnToMain", "DisplayClient", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <div style ="float: left">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.FirstName)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.LastName)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Dob)

Comment: Because the data is no longer in the URL you will have to load it from somewhere else. Normally in the controller I would take that ID from the route data and query the database for the record, populate a view model and pass that to the view for templating.

Comment: Right. So I will need to go back to my controller and query the db to retrieve the record?

Comment: In my experience thats how most web apps would do it, yes.